# Kotlin/Java, string array not yet initialized at method call

Tags: java, exception, null, kotlin

In one program of mine I got a null exception and debugging the code I found out it was because one of my [`String` array](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut11/blinnVsPhongLighting.kt#L80) ([java](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/main/tut11/BlinnVsPhongLighting.java#L84)):

```
val FRAGMENTS = arrayOf("phong-lighting", "phong-only", "blinn-lighting", "blinn-only")
```

was not yet initialized when I needed it in a successive [class method](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut11/blinnVsPhongLighting.kt#L117) ([java](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/main/tut11/BlinnVsPhongLighting.java#L126-L133)):

```
fun initializePrograms(gl: GL3) {

    programs = Array(LightingModel.MAX, {
        ProgramPairs(
                ProgramData(gl, "pn.vert", FRAGMENTS[it] + ".frag"),
                ProgramData(gl, "pcn.vert", FRAGMENTS[it] + ".frag"))
    })
    unlit = UnlitProgData(gl, "pos-transform.vert", "uniform-color.frag")
}
```

If I move it inside:

```
fun initializePrograms(gl: GL3) {
    val FRAGMENTS = arrayOf("phong-lighting", "phong-only", "blinn-lighting", "blinn-only")
    ...
}
```

Then everything fine.. why?

Ps: same code and same behavious also in java

Edit: don't get confused, that `init` is not the `class init`, it extends the [Framework](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut11/blinnVsPhongLighting.kt#L36) method [here](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/main/framework/Framework.java#L99)

Edit2: `initializePrograms()` doesn't get called from the super constructor. It's called from [`init(GL3 gl)`](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/main/tut11/blinnVsPhongLighting.kt#L84) which override [Framework.init(GL3 gl) which gets called from Framework.init(GLAutoDrawable autoDrawable)](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/main/framework/Framework.java#L95-L100), which shall be called from the [Animator](https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/modern-jogl-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/main/framework/Framework.java#L73) just once at begin which should be another thread.

Comment: Isn't the class method called inside the super constructor? If it is, then the reason is that the super constructor is called before the properties are initialized.

Comment: Yeah I thought that and checked it and I don't think it does. This is a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: I don't know much about Kotlin, can you identify the variables with keywords, either private or public, outside the method  and see if it works?

Comment: @hotkey No, it doesn't.`initializePrograms()` gets called from `init(GL3 gl)` which override `Framework.init(GL3 gl)` which gets called from `Framework.init(GLAutoDrawable autoDrawable)`, which shall be called from the `Animator` just once at begin which should be another thread.

Comment: @In-youngChoung, you can check out the parallel java code (it's referenced in the parenthesis)

Comment: Just realized, the `Animator` gets initialized and started in the constructor... it may be that the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason

If method `initializePrograms` is invoked in the superclass constructor, the crash is an expected behavior. Properties of the class are initialized after object is constructed, so they are uninitialized until then.

In that case, because the `arrayOf` function is an inline function, it is clearly visible on decompiled class:

```
public final class Test {
   @NotNull
   private final String[] FRAGMENTS;
   ...

   public Test() {
      super();
      String[] elements$iv = new String[]{"phong-lighting", "phong-only", "blinn-lighting", "blinn-only"};
      Object[] var4 = (Object[])elements$iv;
      this.FRAGMENTS = (String[])var4;
   }
}
```

notice the constructor of `Test` class and how properties are initialized after call to `super()`.

Note that if you would use not-inline function to initialize that property (for example `listOf`) the initialization will be joined with declaration, but that is effectively the same thing, just not as explicit. In Java this field would also be initialized after constructor has finished.

```
public final class Test {
   @NotNull
   private final List FRAGMENTS = CollectionsKt.listOf(new String[]{"phong-lighting", "phong-only", "blinn-lighting", "blinn-only"});
   ...
}
```

### Solution

Most likely what you're trying to achieve (considering the all caps `FRAGMENTS`) is to declare then as a static field. In Kotlin you can do that for example by nesting it in a `companion object` in particular class.

```
class Test {
    ...
    companion object {
        val FRAGMENTS = arrayOf("phong-lighting", "phong-only", "blinn-lighting", "blinn-only")
    }
}
```

then, as you can see on decompiled class, it is declared as a static field and initialized in `static` block:

```
public final class Test {
   @NotNull
   private static final String[] FRAGMENTS;
   ...

   static {
      String[] elements$iv = new String[]{"phong-lighting", "phong-only", "blinn-lighting", "blinn-only"};
      FRAGMENTS = (String[])((Object[])elements$iv);
   }
}
```